# Problema JSON con request NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Hola estoy trabajando con nodejs para crear mi propia API, pero para hacerlo yo pido los datos de otro API

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const request = require('request');

router.get('/randomUser',(req, res) => {
    request('https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=login,picture', function(error, response, body) {
        res.json(body);   
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

estoy utilizando request para interrogar la api, pero al momento de recuperar el BODY pero me devuelve esto

> "{\"results\":[{\"login\":{\"username\":\"lazyswan228\",\"password\":\"marianne\",\"salt\":\"2e0csmRo\",\"md5\":\"5d80a882baf30de55c11f4cc2d336744\",\"sha1\":\"684e46e262838036e1fa4fd20dea3f684e42110f\",\"sha256\":\"42ed12f507e14149bdace829a2bcc4c09966648bef7ae1435ebcd0ad4d776768\"},\"picture\":{\"large\":\"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/42.jpg\",\"medium\":\"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/42.jpg\",\"thumbnail\":\"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/42.jpg\"}}],\"info\":{\"seed\":\"14f7671e0390d291\",\"results\":1,\"page\":1,\"version\":\"1.1\"}}"

Comment: Eso no es un error, es el JSON completo que estás solicitando

Comment: pero no viene en el formato que deberia ser, entiendo que la API me devuelve un json y con la funcion request vuelvo a crear un JSON entonces, que deberia de hacer para respetar el formato JSON, por que asi como esta no podria recorrerlo

Comment: Necesitas parsearlo ya que estás usando express deja busco cómo se hace

Comment: Si porque como lo estoy haciendo esta poniendo "/" esto y hace que se corte todo

Comment: BUSca en github la librería body parser esa te ayudará

Comment: res.json(parse.json(body)); intenté esto pero no muestra nada

Comment: aun no encuentro el problema

Answer (score 2):

Sucede que tienes el JSON como un `string`, eso esta bien. Necesitas convertirlo en un objeto para poder trabajar con el.

Usa `var bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body)` para que conviertas el JSON en un objeto de JavaScript y puedas mapear la información que tiene o lo puedas visualizar sin ser un string.

Recomiendo que lo hagas en un try-catch `JSON.parse()` arroja excepciones si el JSON no cumple el estándar.

Para convertirlo de nuevo a un `string` necesitas usar `JSON.stringify(body)` de hecho, es la manera correcta de mandar un JSON como respuesta a un cliente.